# Detach a policy from an IAM user using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam

The following code attaches an existing IAM policy "**policy_1**" to an existing IAM user "**user_1**"

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  user       = "user_1"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/policy_1"

}
```

I need help on how to remove the same policy from "**user_1**" using Terraform. Thanks!

I tried an alternative "aws_iam_user_policy_detachment" , but such a function does not exist. I am aware this can be done via AWS CLI simply by using `detach-user-policy` but we require it to be done via Terraform.

Comment: Removing that statement will terraform cause to detach it. Terraform is declarative - what you write will be deployed, it you remove something from the code then the difference between the old description and the new description will be created / removed / updated.

Comment: In other words if you add a `aws_iam_user_policy_attachment` a policy will now be attached, if you remove a `aws_iam_user_policy_attachment` the previously attached policy will now be detached. It does not make sense to explicitly declare a detachment.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I am not clear how to `remove` it now. Can you please give the `command` as an answer? Is there a dependency on the machine from which I execute the attach `terraform apply`? Does the `detach` have to happen from the same machine?

Comment: You do know about terraform state files where terraform stores its state, aka which resources it controls and deployed and with what configuration?

Comment: I just did some initial research not in depth, but I got the attach working so thought detach would be simple enough. Do you think that Terraform is the wrong choice for this operation? Is AWS CLI a better option? We add and remove users all the time via GUI and want to avoid that as it causes oversight.

Comment: Then terraform is absolutely the wrong tool for you.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 , but why the downvote? I would think the question is valid though. You can state your response about intended usage of Terraform and I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: No need, explaining terraform and stating its purposes should be done and is done by the terraform docs and website, does not warrant an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform creates resources, which it then manages. When you run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, terraform finds the difference between your described state and the existing state, and adds or deletes resources as needed.

There are three ways you could delete this.

## The Easy Way

If you have a valid state file with this resource in it, just delete the code and run `terraform apply`.

## The Hard Way

If you don't have a state file that manages this resource, you need to create one. Use `terraform import` to begin managing this resource.

```
terraform import aws_iam_user_policy_attachment.test-attach user_1/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/policy_1
```

The ID you need for terraform import will depend on the resource - [check your provider's documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_user_policy_attachment#import) for how to find it.

Then delete the code defining `aws_iam_user_policy_attachment.test-attach`, and run `terraform apply` to create the new state without the resource in it.

## The Extremely Easy Way

`terraform destroy` will delete every item in the local state file. It's a good way to clean up experiments.